# How to deny direct access to wp-cron.php to avoid attacks?

Tags: wordpress, security

I've noticed some recent activity on one of my sites - it appears someone is directly calling the wp-cron.php file:

[image: AWStats]

The only reason I can think someone would be doing that is an attempt to overload the server, right? My question is this - is there any way to prevent it from being called directly?

I know you can disable wp-cron.php being called every page load like this:

```
define('DISABLE_WP_CRON', true);
```

but is there a way to prevent is being called directly? Is it something I should even be worried about?

Comment: Related: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/253315/should-i-disable-wp-cron-and-instead-trigger-wp-cron-php-from-server-every-few-m

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as you don't have any big tasks in your cron there is nothing to worry about.

If you disable it then what the "attacker" could do is to simply try accessing other file.I can bet that hitting your site directly will make much bigger load on your server than this run of wp-cron.php alone ;)

Especially that wp-cron is being run as well when the page is getting loaded in a regular way (so load from it is "included" in regular traffic anyway).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Nginx, you can deny access like this:

```
## deny access because wp-cron.php is triggered via crontab ##
    location /wp-cron.php {
        deny all;
    }
```

This assumes you are calling wp-cron.php another way, such as via server crontab, or via WP-CLI on a regular schedule. Do not use the above code unless you have done this!

We are doing this in SlickStack by default:

https://github.com/littlebizzy/slickstack/blob/master/modules/nginx/sites/production.txt