# How to disable the WP_CRON correctly?

Tags: wordpress, cron

I did add the line `define('DISABLE_WP_CRON', true);` in `wp-config.php` and then restart the HTTP service, but for some reason, I still see the following message in my HTTP access log?

To, me it still calling the `WP_CRON?` anyone know why?

> POST /wp-cron.php?doing_wp_cron=1544709413.1346800327301025390625
>   HTTP/1.1" 200

Comment: please see this link https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/253315/should-i-disable-wp-cron-and-instead-trigger-wp-cron-php-from-server-every-few-m

Comment: Do you have a server cron set up by any chance?

Comment: not set the cron yet.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50979541/direct-access-to-wp-cron-php